# How can I change the number of breaks of x axis for each graph individually for each facet in a facet_grid in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

How can I change the number of breaks of x axis for each graph individually for each facet in a facet_grid?
I would like to modify the x-axis separately for each facet. I have tried with scale_x_continuos(breaks =..., n.breaks = ...) but I can't.
I also removed the theme_set(theme_paleo(8)) with theme_replace and tried with theme(axis.x.text =, axis.ticks =, etc etc) but without positive result, anyone who can help me please.

This is the example for stratigraphic diagrams in this link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidypaleo/vignettes/strat_diagrams.html

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidypaleo)
theme_set(theme_paleo(8))

data("alta_lake_geochem")

alta_lake_geochem

alta_plot <- ggplot(alta_lake_geochem, aes(x = value, y = depth)) +
  geom_lineh() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  facet_geochem_gridh(vars(param)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Depth (cm)")

alta_plot
```

[alta_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OF9Z.png)

Comment: Have you attempted to add the scales = "free" argument to facet_geochem_gridh()?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't look the way it should look, I only want for example, two or three labels for each facet, maybe the most accessible for me is to edit it in an external editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is the `ggh4x` package which via `facetted_pos_scales` allows to set the scales individually for each facet. In the code below I use `facetted_pos_scales` to set the breaks for the first and the third facet, while for all other facets the default is used (`NULL`).

Note 1: `facetted_pos_scales`  requires to the free the x scale via `scales="free_x"`.

Note 2: To make `facetted_pos_scales` work with `scale_y_reverse` I had to move `scale_y_reverse` inside `facetted_pos_scales` too.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidypaleo)
library(ggh4x)

theme_set(theme_paleo(8))

data("alta_lake_geochem")

ggplot(alta_lake_geochem, aes(x = value, y = depth)) +
  geom_lineh() +
  geom_point() +
  facet_geochem_gridh(vars(param), scales = "free_x") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Depth (cm)") +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    x = list(
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:8),
      NULL,
      scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 10),
      NULL
    ),
    y = list(
      scale_y_reverse()
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Huh I'm surprised it works with the facet, but good to know :)

Comment: @teunbrand Haha. `facetted_pos_scales` is great work. One of my favorites. The only issue I ran into was with the scale_y_reverse. Not sure whether this is a bug or whether I missed something. But the only way to make the code work was to move it inside `facetted_pos_scale` too. I already checked for a simpler example and ran into the same issue.

Comment: Yeah I'll admit that is less than ideal, I'll have a look into it tomorrow

Comment: @stefan Thank you very much, it worked perfectly for me, the ggh4x package is great, in other similar questions I noticed that it was necessary to formulate specific functions to modify the scales manually in the facet, but this package does it better, greetings.